Change global and local planners on distance to goal via behavior tree
When the robot approaches a charging station (certain distance to goal), I'd like to change global and/or local planners.
One way could definitely be for the local planner to just deal with it internally but I thought this would also be a good exercise to get some practice with behavior trees.
I'm using the Nav2 stack and I'll make a custom plugin to detect when the robot is within a certain distance from the goal.
For my experiments, I have been using the DistanceTraveled condition but I can't figure out how to make the behavior tree stop the current navigation and start a new one with different planners.
How would you design a BT that does the abovementioned?
